# How can I retrieve the text of a P tag INCLUDING any embedded strong tags using IWebElement?

Tags: c#, selenium, automated-tests

I'm using the **Selenium WebDriver** NuGet package for C#. As part of my tests, I'm checking the text of a paragraph. However, the HTML for the paragraph looks like this:

```
<p>This is <strong>bold</strong>.</p>
```

...and if I have an `IWebElement` representing the `p` tag, then the `.Text` property returns

> This is .

In other words, it only returns the text from the `p` tag, and not from the embedded `strong` tag.

There doesn't seem to be any method or property on `IWebElement` that would allow me to get the full text of the `p` tag and its children.

So... how can it be done?

Comment: Can you post the code where you are "finding" your p-element? just in case...

Comment: I believe an issue somewhere outside of `.Text`. The property should return whole text (including embedded strong tags). Maybe, there are few web elements on the page and you are using wrong web element which actually has only `This is .` OR maybe something wrong with strong element (e.g. it's hidden for some reasons)

Comment: @drkthng: from memory, it's just `var p = webDriver.FindElementById("theId");` or some variant thereof - but see my answer: apparently I need to cast the `IWebElement` to a concrete class(?!).

Comment: @drets: It was definitely the correct element. Problem now solved - see my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm out of the office right now, but my colleague informs me that the problem can be resolved by casting the `IWebElement` returned by `GetElementById` to `RemoteWebElement` and then calling the `Text` property on that.

This is very surprising - I would have thought that `Text` would be a virtual property, and that the behaviour would be defined by the *run-time* type, not the *compile-time* type.

### UPDATE

It appears that my colleague was mistaken. Casting to `RemoteWebElement` did not fix the problem. Rather, it seems that breaking in the debugger and inspecting the `Text` property caused it to return the correct value.

I've now tried to reproduce this problem in a minimal program (see below), and (surprise!) I can't reproduce it. The `Text` property is behaving correctly. I'll continue to investigate what's different about my real setup.

```
namespace SeleniumTest
{
    using System;
    using System.Linq;

    using OpenQA.Selenium.IE;
    using OpenQA.Selenium.Support.UI;

    public class Program
    {
        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            const string ExamplePageUrl = "http://www.nngroup.com/consulting/ux-research-usability-testing/";

            var webDriver = new InternetExplorerDriver();

            webDriver.Navigate().GoToUrl(ExamplePageUrl);

            var wait = new WebDriverWait(webDriver, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10));

            wait.Until(w => w.Title == "Nielsen Norman Group: UX Research, Training, and Consulting");

            var paras = webDriver.FindElementsByTagName("p");

            var para = paras.FirstOrDefault(p => p.Text.Contains("We test your website or application"));

            if (para == null)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Dang. Looks like the website changed.");
            }
            else
            {
                Console.WriteLine(para.Text);
            }

            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I believe this thing is worth to mention in https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/issues